# rsync --link-dest only matching hard-links at the end of the overall transfer

Tags: rsync, backup, hard-link

This command is used in a script used for creating regular backups:

```bash
rsync -aP --link-dest="$BACKUP_DIR/Latest/TheProject" \
    "$SOURCE_DIR/" "$BACKUP_DIR/inProgress/TheProject"
```

- `$SOURCE_DIR` is the "live" location of the files to copy, e.g `/opt/TheProject`.
- `$BACKUP_DIR/Latest` is a soft link to whatever the latest timestamp was, e.g. `$BACKUP_DIR/20220714-0000`. (At the end of the script, that `$BACKUP_DIR/inProgress` directory is moved to the current timestamp, e.g. `$BACKUP_DIR/20220714-0000`.)
- `$SOURCE_DIR` and `$BACKUP_DIR` are on different file systems.

Some large files within the project almost never change, hence the use of `--link-dest`.

It works resonably well and the hard links work (as seen with with `ls -i`), so for example `$BACKUP_DIR/20220714-0000/somedir/bigfile1.bin` will have the same inode as the previous version `$BACKUP_DIR/20220713-0000/somedir/bigfile1.bin` and so on.

The problem is that this hard-linking only seems to happen **at the end** of the whole `rsync` operation.

While `rsync` is running, `$BACKUP_DIR/inProgress/somedir/bigfile1.bin` actually has a different inode (even once it's fully copied and other files are being processed).

The downside is that it needs enough space to create temporary copies of all the files in the origin first, even if most of it will be freed once the `rsync` command has finished running.

For example, if there are ten 1GB files that never change and one 1KB file that changes between backups, it still needs 10GB of free space to perform that backup, even though only about 1KB of extra disk space will be used in the end (since the unmodified files will have been hard-linked, eventually).

I've tried `-H` and `--inplace`, but it didn't seem to help. Is there an option to make `rsync` create those hard-links as it progresses (so that it would only need at least enough free space for the largest file, but not necessarily all of them)?

Comment: (1/3) I can't reproduce a test scenario. I've used `mkdir -p /tmp/opt/TheProject /tmp/backup_dir/20220714-0000; ln -s /tmp/backup_dir/20220714-0000 /tmp/backup_dir/Latest; date >/tmp/opt/TheProject/date2; who >/tmp/opt/TheProject/who1; ps -ef >/tmp/opt/TheProject/ps1; rsync -aP --link-dest=/tmp/backup_dir/Latest/TheProject /tmp/opt/TheProject /tmp/backup_dir/inProgress/TheProject` but I get the error `rsync: [Receiver] mkdir "/tmp/backup_dir/inProgress/TheProject" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: (2/3) If I `mkdir -p /tmp/backup_dir/inProgress` then the `rsync` succeeds but you end up with `TheProject/TheProject` in the target directory. I'm wondering if the missing trailing slashes on the source or destination directories (and `--link-dest`) the cause of your issue

Comment: (3/3) The other possibility is that because it's a local-to-local filesystem copy, changes are handled with the fallback _replace and copy entirely_, Thinking about it, this would explain why you're seeing a copy followed by the "oops, it's the same, so let's link it" scenario

Comment: @roaima Thank you. Sorry, I've realised I'd forgotten a slash in the question, but I had also forgotten an important details: `$SOURCE_DIR` and `$BACKUP_DIR` are on different file systems

Comment: You're using `rsync -aP` and definitely not including the --checksum (`-c`) option too?Also, please ensure that `$RSYNC_PARTIAL_DIR` is not set in the environment